# How to iterate table and store list for each group for sequential analysis?

Tags: python, sequential

I need the program to return a list of lists in which the lists are the activities of each person, i.e. grouped by person - starting with a table of the columns person and activity.

For example, the test of column ['1', '1', '2'] and activity column ['a','b','a'] should return [['a','b'], ['a']], since person '1' has the activities 'a' and 'b', while person '2' has activity 'a'.

The purpose is to analyse sequences or flows of activities.

I have tried the below:

```
#having a table with columns person, activity and day, stored in lists:
person=['1','2','2','2','3','3']
activity=['a','b','c','d','b','c']

#starting with an empty list to store the lists
list_of_lists=[]

#starting with an empty current list
current_list=[]

#iterating each row
for i in range(len(person)):

#if the list of list is empty (in the beginning)
    if len(list_of_lists)==0:

#append the i'th activity in current list
        current_list.append(activity[i])

#otherwise if the i'th person is the same as the latter, append to the same list
    elif person[i]==person[i-1]:
        current_list.append(activity[i])

#otherwise (if it iterates over a a new person) store the current list and create a new list
    else:
        list_of_lists.append(current_list)
        current_list=list()
```

Comment: When you trace this with a debugger, what is the first point where things behave differently than you expected?

Answer (score 0):

`list_of_lists` starts off being empty; since it doesn't get changed in that case, it *never* gets changed, which is why it is empty at the end.  (Nothing is getting "overwritten").

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to do grouping among iterables is using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

first = itemgetter(0)
second = itemgetter(1)

pairs = sorted(zip(person, activity), key=first)  # data must be sorted prior to groupby

[list(map(second, v)) for _, v in groupby(pairs, key=first)]

[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Thank you. I will take a closer look at these tools. The itemgetter is quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

As @Scott Hunter says `list_of_lists` starts empty and stays empty. Another problem with your code would be making sure the final `current_list` gets added to `list_of_lists`. You could adjust your code like this:

```
persons = ['1','2','2','2','3','3']
activities = ['a','b','c','d','b','c']
list_of_lists = []
current_list = []
for i in range(len(persons)):
    if i==0:  # use i == 0 instead of len(list_of_lists)==0 as the starting condition
        current_list.append(activities[i])
    elif persons[i]==persons[i-1]:
        current_list.append(activities[i])
    else:
        list_of_lists.append(current_list)
        current_list=[activities[i]]   # remember to add the current activity here
if current_list:     # after loop has finished still need to add the current list
    list_of_lists.append(current_list)
```

This can be simplified a lot using `zip` and a 'lagged' version of the `person` list.

```
result = []
for person, previous, activity in zip(persons, [None] + persons, activities):
    if person == previous:
        result[-1].append(activity)
    else:
        result.append([activity])
```

Comment: Thank you, and well elaborated with both versions! How does "[None] + persons" work exactly?

Comment: By adding `None` to the start of the list you shift all the other persons one position to the right. Zipping the shifted version to the original version of the list allows you to compare each person to the previous person.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby, islice


people = ["1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3"]
activities = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "c"]

activities_iter = iter(activities)

activity_groups = [list(islice(activities_iter, len(list(group)))) for _, group in groupby(people)]
print(activity_groups)
```

Output:

```
[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Thanks! I will take a closer look at this toolkit. What does the underscore ("for _,") do in this case? And how would you go about iterating over additional columns, for instance a date column?

Comment: `_` is just the name / identifier of a variable, just like `group` is. It's typically used as a variable name to indicate that the captured variable isn't significant - `itertools.groupby` yields a key and group, and in this case I only care about the group. What would be the desired output of iterating over an additional date column? Would it simply be split up into sublists with the same length as the split up activities sublists?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The desired output of iterating over an additional date column would be to enrich the flow / sequential analysis with a time dimension. My initial thought would be to structure data differently and use 2D arrays (in which each list is a row) - any thoughts on that?

Comment: I mean, if you have control over what the data looks like in the first place, I would probably go with a dictionary. What I meant was, what would some example output look like?